# Network Media Player with Other OS option

Tags: video, operating-systems, tv

Not sure this is the right SE site to post this on but figure from the faq: "and is not about... consumer electronics such as media players, cell phones or smart phones, except when **designing these products or hacking their electronics for other uses**" this probably fits the bill.

Is there any known network media player that allows for an "Other OS" option?  Take for example the Apple TV, or the WD Live TV, etc systems, which are really small form factors, have decent hard drives, have great options for hooking up displays (Composite, Component, HDMI/DVI/etc.).  The PS3 used to allow the Other OS option but then they removed it for unknown reasons, I would love something like.

I need a hardware device that I can install Windows on (I know, probably a long shot).  Does anyone know of any hardware device that will allow this?

Now, there is a small form factor PC device from Dell called the Zino (as an example), which would work out very good, except that it only has VGA/HDMI output, my needs call for the older composite, component outputs to work as well as an option for hooking up to a TV.

Comment: for a 'proper' windows install, as opposed to embedded, you need an x86 based system of some sort. If you went for linux or some manner of BSD, you have a lot more choice

Comment: Windows is not flexible, so you need a PC, and installing Windows on a PC doesn't count as "other uses". The root problem is that Windows is closed source, so you can't very well hack it.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt you are going to find a modern HTPC/ Small Form Factor with component and you really shouldn't be looking for one either...

Your best bet would be to get something like the Zino or Asus EEE Desktop or build your own with and nVidia Ion board and then get an adapter that lets you go from [HDMI to Component](http://www.google.com/search?q=dvi%20to%20composite&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a#sclient=psy&hl=en&client=firefox-a&hs=iVR&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&biw=1680&bih=961&tbm=shop&source=hp&q=hdmi%20to%20component&aq=f&aqi=g5&aql=&oq=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=435e185a007639bf) or something of the sort.

I have not personally used one of these types of converters but there are tons of different ones so they should work :) maybe someone else can speak on it or recommend a brand.

Why do you want to use Windows for a network media player anyways? You can use something dedicated to media playing like XBMC... you could even go old school and get an [original xbox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xbox) and modify it with XBMC and it can play non-HD content :)